# Error compiling for Windows on Linux using the MinGW-w64 suite

Tags: linux, mingw-w64

When I use simple hello world c program it works perfectly fine and generates a proper exe file for Windows 64 bit.But when I use some code which requires lib and include files to be added in the command then it generates the following error. If I use simple gcc command this works perfectly fine.

==================================================

**Command Executed.** 
myroot@ubuntu:/home/mysystem/Desktop# /opt/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /home/mysystem/Desktop/hello.c -I /home/mysystem/Desktop/oracle/include/ -L /opt/Db/lib/ -L /opt/Db/9/lib -ldld -o /home/mysystem/mystem/testme.exe

===================================================

**Error** 
/opt/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.5.4/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -ldld collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

===================================================

Need Help Plz

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to reason that it is not get the required library to execute the program as ld is needed to execute.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Using gcc does find the library and executes well,why not with mingw..any workaround to make sure that the lib is recognized.

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_External_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW This would show you how to point the library using MinGW